Tags covered by a circle

am I the only one having this issue? is this a known issue? (will close the question if so)

That looks like the eye that indicates watched tags. In which case, no, I'm not having this issue.

are you using the dark-mode of SO or the dark-mode offered by your browser/OS. In the latter case please add browser brand/version and OS

technically I am also using a plugin called dark reader on top of the SO's dark mode, I am using brave 1.66.118

but I have been using it for months now and that's the first time I see the issue

Are you running any custom stylesheets by any chance? I had to adjust mine due to some CSS conflicts with the latest tag redesign

Not any I know of, unless the plugin I mentioned uses some
